# Get randomly error-code STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA at creating a new room for multiplayer game

Tags: android, real-time, google-play-games, multiplayer

I am developing a real time multiplayer game. The game itself is working fine. I am struggling with a room creation error which occurs randomly. I use google play games as a framework. The game concept is managing an amount of players from 3 up to 7 for a single room. In 10 attempts to build a game, the error occurs about 2 times. I am receiving the error at the method `public void onRoomCreated(int statusCode, Room room) {...}`. When the error occurs a participant is not able to create a room. However, if I check participant.isConnected() it returns true.

This is the received error code:

```
Error: onRoomCreated, status 4
```

According to the developer docs i found out the meaning:

> public static final int STATUS_NETWORK_ERROR_NO_DATA
>
> A network error occurred while attempting to retrieve fresh data, and
>   no data was available locally.
>
> Constant Value: 4

If I try to restart the game after the error occurs, the problem persists. Even if I try it 100 times. If instead I leave the room and wait 2 minutes, a new connection attempt is always successful.

I have noticed the following Warning is always before:

```
02-10 18:26:19.421: W/libjingle(1933): Warning(openssladapter.cc:388): ContinueSSL -- error -1
02-10 18:26:19.421: W/libjingle(1933): Warning(openssladapter.cc:397): OpenSSLAdapter::Error(ContinueSSL, -1)
```

I didn't found any ressource to this warning. Does anyone know what this warning means?

I also figured out:

- It also happens when I just booted the device.
- It can affect just one device or multiple devices at once per game.
- It doesn't matter if I play on an emulator or on a real device.
- It doesn't matter if I play a automatch-game or a invitation-game.
- If i run several emulators at the same time (game-start), it can affect only one emulator (even if they have the same network connection).

Here is the stacktrace (error occurs near center line):

```
02-10 18:26:17.129: E/WVMExtractor(130): Failed to open libwvm.so
02-10 18:26:17.213: D/dalvikvm(694): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1585K, 25% free 10919K/14407K, paused 18ms+42ms, total 421ms
02-10 18:26:17.301: V/BaseAuthAsyncOperation(694): All scopes had been granted in the past, skip access token fetching
02-10 18:26:17.389: V/BaseAuthAsyncOperation(694): access token request successful
02-10 18:26:17.781: E/WVMExtractor(130): Failed to open libwvm.so
02-10 18:26:17.817: D/ButtonClicker2000(3532): debug onConnected() called. Sign in successful!
02-10 18:26:17.817: D/ButtonClicker2000(3532): debug Sign-in succeeded.
02-10 18:26:18.069: E/WVMExtractor(130): Failed to open libwvm.so
02-10 18:26:18.157: D/dalvikvm(528): GC_CONCURRENT freed 866K, 24% free 7904K/10375K, paused 14ms+1ms, total 274ms
02-10 18:26:18.465: E/WVMExtractor(130): Failed to open libwvm.so
02-10 18:26:18.697: E/WVMExtractor(130): Failed to open libwvm.so
02-10 18:26:19.005: D/dalvikvm(528): GC_CONCURRENT freed 966K, 25% free 7864K/10375K, paused 20ms+1ms, total 67ms
02-10 18:26:19.005: D/dalvikvm(528): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
02-10 18:26:19.109: I/libjingle(1933): Token type:OAuth2
02-10 18:26:19.109: I/libjingle(1933): Final XMPP server hostname talk.google.com port to 5222
02-10 18:26:19.165: I/libjingle(1933): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
02-10 18:26:19.197: D/dalvikvm(3532): GC_CONCURRENT freed 895K, 19% free 9093K/11143K, paused 24ms+1ms, total 51ms
02-10 18:26:19.221: I/libjingle(1933): BeginSSL: talk.google.com
02-10 18:26:19.249: W/libjingle(1933): Warning(openssladapter.cc:388): ContinueSSL -- error -1
02-10 18:26:19.253: W/libjingle(1933): Warning(openssladapter.cc:397): OpenSSLAdapter::Error(ContinueSSL, -1)
02-10 18:26:19.281: I/libjingle(1933): SSL Cleanup
02-10 18:26:19.293: I/libjingle(1933): Token type:OAuth2
02-10 18:26:19.297: I/libjingle(1933): Final XMPP server hostname talk.google.com port to 5222
02-10 18:26:19.341: I/libjingle(1933): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
02-10 18:26:19.393: I/libjingle(1933): BeginSSL: talk.google.com
02-10 18:26:19.421: W/libjingle(1933): Warning(openssladapter.cc:388): ContinueSSL -- error -1
02-10 18:26:19.421: W/libjingle(1933): Warning(openssladapter.cc:397): OpenSSLAdapter::Error(ContinueSSL, -1)
02-10 18:26:19.441: D/ButtonClicker2000(3532): onRoomCreated(4, null)
02-10 18:26:19.441: E/ButtonClicker2000(3532): debug Error: onRoomCreated, status 4
02-10 18:26:19.441: I/System.out(3532): debug apiclient connect:true, isConnecting():false
02-10 18:26:19.441: I/System.out(3532): debug dump output:
02-10 18:26:19.441: I/System.out(3532): debug dump mState=CONNECTED mResuming=false mWorkQueue.size()=0 mUnconsumedRunners.size()=0
02-10 18:26:19.441: I/System.out(3532): debug dump Plus.API:
02-10 18:26:19.441: I/System.out(3532): debug dump   mConnectState=CONNECTED mService=com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.IPlusService@535219a4
02-10 18:26:19.441: I/System.out(3532): debug dump Games.API:
02-10 18:26:19.441: I/System.out(3532): debug dump   mConnectState=CONNECTED mService=com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService@535e8a28
02-10 18:26:19.457: I/libjingle(1933): SSL Cleanup
02-10 18:26:19.485: D/ChimeraCfgMgr(694): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games
02-10 18:26:19.489: D/ChimeraModuleLdr(694): Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded
02-10 18:26:19.589: W/EGL_genymotion(3532): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-10 18:26:19.597: D/OpenGLRenderer(3532): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8181100): name, size, mSize = 290, 4896, 129800
02-10 18:26:19.625: D/OpenGLRenderer(3532): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8193580): name, size, mSize = 291, 4896, 134696
02-10 18:26:19.637: D/OpenGLRenderer(3532): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8198388): name, size, mSize = 292, 4, 134700
02-10 18:26:22.637: D/OpenGLRenderer(3532): TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb8184e70): name, size, mSize = 305, 100, 134800
02-10 18:26:22.765: W/genymotion_audio(130): out_write() limiting sleep time 46802 to 39909
```

Another example with the same error:

```
    02-10 18:37:15.200: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 412296 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.200: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 396104 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.204: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 379912 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.216: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 363720 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.216: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 347528 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.220: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 331336 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.228: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 315144 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.232: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 298952 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.232: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 282760 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.244: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 266568 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.244: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 250376 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.244: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 234184 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.248: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 217992 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.252: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 201800 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.256: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 185608 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.256: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 169416 bytes, got 15540 
02-10 18:37:15.276: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 153876 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.276: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 137684 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.280: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 121492 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.284: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 105300 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.292: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 89108 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.296: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 72916 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.300: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 56724 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.308: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 40532 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.312: E/SocketStream(130): readFully was waiting for 24340 bytes, got 16192 
02-10 18:37:15.368: D/ButtonClicker2000(3540): Select players UI succeeded.
02-10 18:37:15.368: D/ButtonClicker2000(3540): Invitee count: 1
02-10 18:37:15.368: D/ButtonClicker2000(3540): Automatch criteria: Bundle[{max_automatch_players=5, min_automatch_players=2, exclusive_bit_mask=0}]
02-10 18:37:15.368: D/ButtonClicker2000(3540): Creating room...
02-10 18:37:15.392: D/ButtonClicker2000(3540): Room created, waiting for it to be ready...
02-10 18:37:15.460: I/Ads(3540): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
02-10 18:37:15.460: I/Ads(3540): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
02-10 18:37:15.484: V/GLSActivity(531): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
02-10 18:37:15.504: I/qtaguid(285): Failed write_ctrl(s 0 10035) res=-1 errno=1
02-10 18:37:15.504: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(285): setKernelCountSet(10035, 0) failed with errno -1
02-10 18:37:15.516: V/GLSActivity(531): AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
02-10 18:37:15.544: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::flush: target size: 2399280
02-10 18:37:15.544: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 12932, 51984, 3946816
02-10 18:37:15.544: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 12933, 51984, 3894832
02-10 18:37:15.544: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 12926, 5184, 3889648
02-10 18:37:15.544: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 12927, 9216, 3880432
02-10 18:37:15.548: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 12928, 5184, 3875248
02-10 18:37:15.548: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 13024, 36864, 3838384
02-10 18:37:15.548: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 13023, 2304, 3836080
02-10 18:37:15.548: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 13028, 36864, 3799216
02-10 18:37:15.552: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 12993, 1048576, 2750640
02-10 18:37:15.552: D/OpenGLRenderer(3368): TextureCache::callback: name, removed size, mSize = 12994, 1048576, 1702064
02-10 18:37:15.628: D/ChimeraCfgMgr(700): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games
02-10 18:37:15.628: D/ChimeraModuleLdr(700): Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded
02-10 18:37:16.356: D/dalvikvm(531): GC_CONCURRENT freed 871K, 14% free 10526K/12103K, paused 13ms+4ms, total 43ms
02-10 18:37:16.456: I/libjingle(1912): Token type:OAuth2
02-10 18:37:16.456: I/libjingle(1912): Final XMPP server hostname talk.google.com port to 5222
02-10 18:37:16.552: I/libjingle(1912): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
02-10 18:37:16.604: I/libjingle(1912): BeginSSL: talk.google.com
02-10 18:37:16.636: W/libjingle(1912): Warning(openssladapter.cc:388): ContinueSSL -- error -1
02-10 18:37:16.636: W/libjingle(1912): Warning(openssladapter.cc:397): OpenSSLAdapter::Error(ContinueSSL, -1)
02-10 18:37:16.664: I/libjingle(1912): SSL Cleanup
02-10 18:37:16.676: I/libjingle(1912): Token type:OAuth2
02-10 18:37:16.676: I/libjingle(1912): Final XMPP server hostname talk.google.com port to 5222
02-10 18:37:16.720: I/libjingle(1912): OpenSSLAdapter::OnConnectEvent
02-10 18:37:16.768: I/libjingle(1912): BeginSSL: talk.google.com
02-10 18:37:16.800: W/libjingle(1912): Warning(openssladapter.cc:388): ContinueSSL -- error -1
02-10 18:37:16.800: W/libjingle(1912): Warning(openssladapter.cc:397): OpenSSLAdapter::Error(ContinueSSL, -1)
02-10 18:37:16.808: D/ButtonClicker2000(3540): onRoomCreated(4, null)
02-10 18:37:16.808: E/ButtonClicker2000(3540): debug Error: onRoomCreated, status 4
02-10 18:37:16.808: I/System.out(3540): debug apiclient connect:true, isConnecting():false
02-10 18:37:16.808: I/System.out(3540): debug dump output:
02-10 18:37:16.808: I/System.out(3540): debug dump mState=CONNECTED mResuming=false mWorkQueue.size()=0 mUnconsumedRunners.size()=0
02-10 18:37:16.808: I/System.out(3540): debug dump Plus.API:
02-10 18:37:16.808: I/System.out(3540): debug dump   mConnectState=CONNECTED mService=com.google.android.gms.plus.internal.IPlusService@539e0a94
02-10 18:37:16.808: I/System.out(3540): debug dump Games.API:
02-10 18:37:16.808: I/System.out(3540): debug dump   mConnectState=CONNECTED mService=com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService@539e1244
02-10 18:37:16.824: D/ChimeraCfgMgr(700): Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.play.games
02-10 18:37:16.824: D/ChimeraModuleLdr(700): Module APK com.google.android.play.games already loaded
02-10 18:37:16.844: I/libjingle(1912): SSL Cleanup
02-10 18:37:16.940: W/EGL_genymotion(3540): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

In this way I build up a game:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.d(TAG, "debug onConnected() called. Sign in successful!");
    Log.d(TAG, "debug Sign-in succeeded.");
    final int MAX_OPPONENTS = 6;
    int min_opponents = 2;
    int opponentsPref = getIntent().getIntExtra(MyIds.MP_MIN_OPPONENTS, MyIds.MP_MIN_OPPONENTS_TWO);
    if(opponentsPref == MyIds.MP_MIN_OPPONENTS_SIX){
        min_opponents = 6;
    }
    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(min_opponents, MAX_OPPONENTS, 0);
    RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setVariant(variant);
    switchToScreen(R.id.mpGamescreen_wait);
    keepScreenOn();
    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, rtmConfigBuilder.build());
}
```

And this is the way, how i leave a room:

```
private synchronized void leaveRoom() {
    Log.d(TAG, "debug Leaving room.");
    switchToScreen(R.id.mpGamescreen_wait);
    if (mRoomId != null && mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.leave(mGoogleApiClient, this, mRoomId);
        mRoomId = null;
        stopKeepingScreenOn();
        Log.d(TAG, "debug leave() called.");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "debug leave() not called.");
        stopKeepingScreenOn();
        if (!isFinishing()){
            finish();               
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onLeftRoom(int statusCode, String roomId) {
    // we have left the room; return to main screen.
    Log.d(TAG, "onLeftRoom, code " + statusCode);
    if (!isFinishing()){
        finish();               
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    if (mRoomId != null && mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        leaveRoom();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

// Handle back key to make sure we cleanly leave a game if we are in the middle of one
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "debug onKeyDown");
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        leaveRoom();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```

Does anyone know why the error occurs? I am thankful for each advice.